# How to do an update or delete query based on a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So when users are online on my website, if they go inactive for more than 15 minutes I want to set their status to idle represented by a column in my "online" table within my database, if they go inactive for more than 30 minutes I want to completely delete the row rather than update a column.

Is there a way to do this in one query? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you delete user? Are this registered users or only guests?

Comment: they're registered users, im deleting their row in the "online" table not the "users" table. Rows are put in the online table when a user signs in

Comment: Why do you have online table? Put datetime field in user table and name it something like "last_active". Update this time field on every user action. If time is older than 15min, user is idle, if time is older than 30min user is not here.

Comment: @glavić I can imagine plenty of situations where you might want an "online user" table in addition to a basic/permanent "user" table.

Comment: @jmilloy: I agree if this online table has some extra data (that i cannot think of any now), that we would not like to have in user table. But if his online table is only user_id and time, then this is bad solution.

Comment: @glavić - not if he has a very large users table but much smaller amount of users online, or if he wants to add guests to the list, etc etc. Having a separate table is handy in lots of situations. It's all about the least amount of processing overheads, forward planning and future proofing the db design.

Comment: Oh. Just got the point of the question, sorry. Deleted my useless answer.

Comment: @glavić if i didnt have an online table then when a user hits the log out button, it would still show the user as online until the last activity field was over 30 mins in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this in one query is to set up a trigger on the table such that ON UPDATE it deletes any rows that are more than the inactivity deletion threshold (30 mins).

But, that's just two queries, ultimately - it's just the DB is executing one after you execute one.

Don't fear multiple queries, they're very fast!